# Facebook Graph for URLs - Getting the number of shares for a group of pages

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-fql

How can we know the sum of all Facebook shares for all URLs that start with:

http://www.guardian.co.uk/artanddesign/

There's an API method for a specific URL that is:

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.guardian.co.uk/artanddesign/2012/feb/19/frank-gehry-new-york-interview

But I can't make it sum all the URLs that start with 
http://www.guardian.co.uk/artanddesign/.

**Notes:**

- I can't iterate trough all the URL's in the directory "artsanddesign".
- Please note that the URL's above are just examples.
- I can't access insights because I don't have permissions to add a meta-tag on the root directory of the site
- Maybe the solution is using the Facebook Query Language (FQL)? How could it work?

Comment: This question is better asked at our sister site stackoverflow as they provide the official support for facebook developers.

Comment: Can someone move it to SO then?

Comment: I've flagged it to the Mods...

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any way to get information for all URLs that match a certain pattern, I think you have to specify the individual URLs manually - this shouldn't be a bug problem if it's your own site, as you'll already have a database of all possible article URLs, but if you're checking someone else's site it could be difficult.

Comment: Thanks @Igy I don't have the DDBB because the website is in a proprietary hosted platform. Assuming I could ask for that DDBB or build it from sitemap.xml, can I make thousands of requests to the FB api from just one IP address?